# Yarn on package.json suddenly creates bugs

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am working in React with react-admin and supabase-js.

I suddenly have a problem when I add, remove, or basically do anything on my package.json file : it doesn't display my React-Admin correctly.
Some CSS is different, and I now have an error from bundle.js when I want to add or edit something in a list :

> Cannot update a component (SaveButton) while rendering a different
> component (TextInput). To locate the bad setState() call inside
> TextInput, follow the stack trace as described in
> https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

The JSX code is correct, for sure.

Fortunately I managed to get back a "clean" node_modules and copy it back in my main folder so that everything works again correctly (no strange CSS or bundle.js errors) but now I am stuck with this node_modules...

Here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@raphiniert/ra-data-postgrest": "1.2.0",
    "@react-admin/ra-form-layout": "^4.5.1",
    "@react-admin/ra-rbac": "^4.2.0",
    "@react-admin/ra-relationships": "^4.1.2",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.26.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jsonexport": "^3.2.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.24",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "ra-i18n-polyglot": "^4.8.3",
    "ra-input-rich-text": "^4.8.3",
    "ra-language-english": "^4.9.2",
    "ra-language-french": "^4.8.3",
    "ra-supabase": "^2.0.3",
    "ra-supabase-language-english": "^2.0.5",
    "ra-supabase-language-french": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-admin": "^4.14.0",
    "react-admin-import-csv": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "emulate": "firebase emulators:start --only hosting",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging yarn start",
    "start:master": "env-cmd -f .env.production yarn start",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging yarn build",
    "deploy:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging yarn build && firebase deploy -P staging --only hosting",
    "deploy:master": "env-cmd -f .env.production yarn build && firebase deploy -P default --only hosting"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.0",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

I have been trying to delete node_module and yarn.lock and then perform a new "yarn" but in vain... I really don't get it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's hard to debug this react issue without the react code but I would not discount the error message that easily. My guess is that your react code has an error that a previous version of react did not enforce but the newer version does and now throws an error. I would look at https://dev.to/console_logs/warning-cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-5bfk to be sure your react code is good. Also be sure to commit your `yarn.lock` changes to avoid dependency issues.

Comment: You most probably have an implementation problem, running yarn will install all the dependencies to the latest in the range you specified in package.json. Was there any breaking changes on one of your package? For sure this is not a dependency a problem

Comment: Hi! I suppose indeed a package did change, but which one? that I don't know... What I do now is try to change packages versions to try and isolate the faulty package.